# EF Core removes EF dependencies during migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I've been trying to set up EFCore with .NET6. When all my Models/Entities are inside a folder, the Initial Migration I ran removes all the dependencies(some) from the project and results in a failed build. But when I initially store my model in the root directory and run the same command it works.

This is the folder structure which causes the issue

[image: This is the folder structure which causes the issue]

[image: The actual issue]

**Update**

The last time I tried migrations worked if I placed the models and entities at the project's root, but now, even if I do, the same error happens. Please help me with this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Visual Studio did not save the changes to the .csproj file on disk when I installed all the NuGet packages which resulted in the build failed error. This issue will not happen when we use visual studio to build the project because it will persist the changes to the disk when we do that but I used the CLI to build and run the migrations which resulted in this error.